# What happens when I initialize a char array without setting the array size in C

Tags: arrays, c, char

When I initialize a char array like `char str1[] = {'a','b','c'}` (array size is not set) and finding it's length using loop until `str1[i] != '\0'`, I get `length = 4`. In contrast, when I initialize like `char str2[10] = {'a','b','c'}` (array size is set) and finding the length using using same way, I get `length = 3`. Why `str1[3]` contains a garbage value but not in `str2[3]`?

Comment: `char str1[] = {'a','b','c'}`, allocates an array of chars with size 3. `char str2[10]` allocates an array of size 10 and you set indexes 0,1,2 with your desired values. The rest are still allocated and available for use, though contain garbage values.

Comment: No element in `str1` is `'\0'` so your loop is going out of bounds, which is undefined behavior

Comment: You probably accessed the first array out of bound causing undefined behavior. The first array is of size 3 while the second one is 10.

Answer (score 6):

`char str1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};` creates an array of 3 characters, with the values `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. The size of the array is 3, which you can see with `sizeof str1` (this returns the number of bytes, but as a `char` is defined to be 1 byte it's the same as the number of elements). Trying to calculate the length of the string contained in this array causes *undefined behavior*, since `str1` does *not* contain a C-style string as it has no `'\0'` terminator. Your loop calculating this goes out of the bounds of the array.

`char str2[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};` creates an array of 10 characters, with the values `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and 7 `'\0'`s. The size of the array is 10. Calculating the length of the string in `str2` gives you 3, since `str2[3]` is `'\0'`;

If you want to create an array containing a C-style string without specifying the size, you can do `char str[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`, or more simply, `char str[] = "abc";`.

Comment: Note: `char str[] = "abc";` is _initialization_ syntax, not assignment. So we can do modification like `str[2] = 'd';` to make `str` becomes `['a', 'b', 'd', '\0']`.